# Porque usar layout antes de carregar as informações?

Tags: html5, css3

Vejo em várias aplicações web que antes de exibir o conteúdo é exibido alguns blocos parecendo uma imagem, os blocos que falo na imagem é os da barra lateral. Porque usam isso e como usar?

Imagem de uma aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Geralmente usam isso pq pegaram um framework pronto que faz assim. Em raros casos, há uma real razão de ser, feita por um desenvolvedor consciente. De qq forma, pode ser que em se tratando deste último caso, saia alguma resposta boa, apesar de ampla a questão.

Comment: Eles usam por questão de experiência de usuário (Design UX) para dar a melhor experiência ao usuário, pois ao abrir, seria bom dar algum feedback ou avisando que está carregando ou montando a estrutura com layout quase pronto. Se fosse nenhum layout ou algo assim, pode levar ao usuário a pensar que está muito lerdo ou travando o que na realidade não é verdade e o que prejudica o aplicativo ou empresa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é chamado de Preload overlay e, como disseram nas outras respostas, é uma prática amigável para com os usuários, mostrando um layout e um aviso de que a página está carregando, por exemplo.

Isso pode ser feito com Jquery/Css/Javascript, usando um código parecido com o abaixo.

**Jquery**

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
  var target = $('#target');

  $('.toggle-loading').click(function () {
    if (target.hasClass('loading')) {
      target.loadingOverlay('remove');
    } else {
      target.loadingOverlay();
    };
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="target" class="loading">
  <div class="loading-overlay">
    <p class="loading-spinner">
      <span class="loading-icon"></span>
      <span class="loading-text">loading</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: "demo";
  src: url('fonts/icons.woff') format("woff"), url('fonts/icons.ttf') format("truetype");
}

@keyframes loadingStart {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#css-input:checked ~ .loading .loading-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-animation: loadingStart 3s 300ms linear 1 both;
  -moz-animation: loadingStart 3s 300ms linear 1 both;
  -o-animation: loadingStart 3s 300ms linear 1 both;
  animation: loadingStart 3s 300ms linear 1 both;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
#css-input:checked ~ .loading .loading-text {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.3125rem;
  text-shadow: white 0 0 1em, white 0 0 0.5em, white 0 0 0.25em;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#css-input:checked ~ .loading .loading-text:after {
  content: "...";
}
#css-input:checked ~ .loading .loading-spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: -3.9375rem auto 0;
  color: #1a1d1d;
  text-align: center;
}
#css-input:checked ~ .loading .loading-icon {
  font-size: 4.8125rem;
  line-height: 5.25rem;
  text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 0 0 0.5em;
  -webkit-animation: loading 1s steps(4) infinite;
  -moz-animation: loading 1s steps(4) infinite;
  -o-animation: loading 1s steps(4) infinite;
  animation: loading 1s steps(4) infinite;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#css-input:checked ~ .loading .loading-icon:before {
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "\e000";
  font-family: "demo";
}
```

Esse exemplo de código eu retirei [daqui](http://jgerigmeyer.github.io/jquery-loading-overlay/demo/).

Caso queira usar um plugin para fazer isso, tem esse [daqui](http://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/)

Answer (score 1):

Quando uma aplicação web tem de carregar muita informação, é melhor apresentar ao utilizador um ecrã assim e carregar os dados "por baixo", em vez de mostrar uma simples pagina em branco sem informação. É uma questão amigável para com os utilizadores.

Para fazer algo assim existem muitas maneiras, sendo uma mais simples a combinação de Javascript / jQuery / AJAX com CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Quando é uma aplicação que tem muitos dados a serem carregados, em vez de adotar uma página em branco com loading, ela apresenta já o modelo do layout sem as informações e um aviso de que está sendo carregada as informações. Isso que acontece aí no caso do Slack, que você exemplificou com a foto.

É preciso usar nesse caso as tecnologias de Front-end, como HTML/CSS e Javascript.